# ASP.NET MVC pass parameter to controller with argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with passing parameter in controller.

I get `id` value in `public ActionResult AddIngridient(int id = 0)` and i need to pass it in `public ActionResult AddIngridient(Ingredients ingridients)` like `IngredientID`. How to do this?

I have model:

```
public partial class Ingredients
{
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AmountID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IngredientTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

And controllers:

```
public ActionResult AddIngridient(int id = 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<Ingredient> ListOfIngridient =  FRE.Ingredient.Select(key => key).ToList();
        ViewBag.IngridientsList = new SelectList(ListOfIngridient,"IngredientID", "IngredientName");

        IEnumerable<Amount> ListOfAmounts = FRE.Amount.Select(key => key).ToList();
        ViewBag.AmountsList = new SelectList(ListOfAmounts, "AmountID", "AmountName");

        ViewBag.ID = id;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddIngridient(Ingredients ingridients)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View looks like:

```
@model FoodRecipes.Models.Ingredients
@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddIngridient";
}

<h2>AddIngridient</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IngredientTypeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.IngridientsList)
<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AmountID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AmountsList)
 <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set the action you want to post? like this: @using(Html.BeginForm("AddIngridient","YourControllerName"))

Comment: @RicardoPontual this is only needed when you want to jump to other controller outside the current route. And, absolutely, not represent a problem in the context of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Html.HiddenFor()` helper.

In your case:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddIngridient","YourControllerName"))
{ 
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IngredientID) //this line 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IngredientTypeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.IngridientsList)
   <br />
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AmountID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AmountsList)
   <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

It will produce `input` type `hidden` with name `IngredientID` that will be passed to server on form **POST**.

Comment: If ViewBag.ID = id, contain value that need to place in model.IngridientID, maybe it should be something like @Html.HiddenFor(model => ViewBag.ID)

Comment: @A191919 no, it' better to set it to ingridientid model property in controller. That's mvc way

Comment: @A191919 The correct helper is: @Html.Hidden("IngedientID", ViewBag.ID). But my answer explains the right way to work with models, considering that you can add more properties to your model, and it is a bad practice to populate ViewBag with properties of the model.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code of AddIngredient Action to return the model:

```
public ActionResult AddIngridient(int id = 0)
{
    IEnumerable<Ingredient> ListOfIngridient =  FRE.Ingredient.Select(key => key).ToList();
    ViewBag.IngridientsList = new SelectList(ListOfIngridient,"IngredientID", "IngredientName");

    IEnumerable<Amount> ListOfAmounts = FRE.Amount.Select(key => key).ToList();
    ViewBag.AmountsList = new SelectList(ListOfAmounts, "AmountID", "AmountName");

    return View(new Ingredients { IngredientID = id });
}
```

And in your view add a input type hidden:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IngredientID)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IngredientTypeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.IngridientsList)
   <br />
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AmountID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AmountsList)
   <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```